# Display HTML in ASP.NET Literal Control

Tags: asp.net

I have the following ASP.NET Literal Control displayed on my page

```
<div class="col-md-8 text-justify">
    <p>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1"
            Mode="PassThrough"
            Text= "<%#:Item.Description %>"          
            runat="server">
        </asp:Literal>

    </p> 
</div>
```

This control is bound to a field in my SQL Server Table and a column called Description in the table contains the text with HTML tags like `<p> <ul> <br>` etc.

However when the text is displayed in the Literal control, it is displayed as-is i.e the HTML does not get rendered.

If the Literal control does not support rendering, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the Literal control. It's the way you embedded the HTML. Try this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1"
        Mode="PassThrough"
        Text= "<%# Item.Description %>"          
        runat="server">
    </asp:Literal>
```

Notice I left out the colon? That colon is there to prevent injection attacks, where the contents of the value being embedded might come from a user. But if you trust the HTML content, then removing the colon will embed the HTML and allow it to render properly instead of escaping it.

Comment: `<%# Item.Description %>` ***not the same*** `<%#:Item.Description %>`  The **colon** ***:*** is the _key_.